# Embedded swift framework with cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I made a private framework that I want to use in different project. I use Cocoapods with this framework for third parties like AFNetworking, Facebook, or SDWebImage. I use an aggregate to build my framework for simulator and devices architectures.

I can build it, without any problem, but when I add my embedded framework to my new project (wrote in Objective-C), I have this error at the launch:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AFNetworking.framework/AFNetworking
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2BE49976-94F8-43C3-BBFF-930F11642DDE/MyPhotoApp.app/Frameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
  Reason: image not found
```

My new project has also Cocoapods with all the required pods of my framework.

The thing I would like, and I can't find how to do it, is to make a framework that depends of Cocoapods, but that does not contains the sources. I would like that the client add itself the necessary pods to its project.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Thank you :)

Comment: You need to add `AFNetworking` in the `Embedded Binaries` of your new project as well.

Comment: Even if it's already linked with Cocoapods in my new project ?

Comment: Could you add your `podfile` please?

Comment: You put me on the good way !! The thing I did not do is to uncomment the "use_frameworks!" on my new framework ! As I use objective-c on my new project, I did not think to uncomment this line... Thank you @Dershowitz123

Comment: Anytime @Max. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

For `Objective-c` projects, **DONOT** uncomment the line `use_frameworks!`. It is meant only for swift projects. For future reference. :)

Comment: I know that use_framework was only for swift. But what is the risk with objective-c ? Now it works and I spent 3 days on it

Comment: `use_frameworks!` means you don't need a bridging header for your objective-c pods in swift. Why would you need a bridging header in an `Objective-c` project which uses an `Objective-c` pod?